# Cassandra administration

Tags: cassandra, client

I am looking for GUI based client for Cassandra database. Two project seems to be workable i.e. helenos, cassandra-cluster-admin. Unfortunately both of these projects seems no more being maintained. I have searched a lot over web but could not find any. Can you please suggest a free tool you know about?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Datastax DevCenter and works so far with basic functionality to write queries, view list of keyspaces and tables.

https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-devcenter-and-development-tools#DataStax-DevCenter

Answer (score 1):

You can use dbeaver (works with many databases):

http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/